# Swift3 Share Extension set configurationItem is wrong

Tags: ios, swift, share

A simple view controller inherited SLComposeServiceViewController. I just override the function configurationItems()

```
class ShareViewController: SLComposeServiceViewController {

override func isContentValid() -> Bool {
    // Do validation of contentText and/or NSExtensionContext attachments here
    return true
}

override func didSelectPost() {
    // This is called after the user selects Post. Do the upload of contentText and/or NSExtensionContext attachments.

    // Inform the host that we're done, so it un-blocks its UI. Note: Alternatively you could call super's -didSelectPost, which will similarly complete the extension context.
    self.extensionContext!.completeRequest(returningItems: [], completionHandler: nil)
}

override func configurationItems() -> [Any]! {
    // To add configuration options via table cells at the bottom of the sheet, return an array of SLComposeSheetConfigurationItem here.
    var item = SLComposeSheetConfigurationItem.init()
    item?.value = "Beijing"
    item?.title = "Location"
    return [item]
}
```

}
when I run the target the host app is safari. then I shared a webpage. But it is wrong

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[_SwiftValue setChangeObserver:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6080002495d0'

However I use the OC write the code, the project is very good.

```
SLComposeSheetConfigurationItem *item = [[SLComposeSheetConfigurationItem alloc]init];
item.title = @"Location";
item.value = @"Beijing";

return @[item];
```

Why? Hope you can help me. Thank you very much!